# Xamarin Pass Entry Value to new page from old

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hi i have a page where i get the user to fill out their fast name and last name and then when they hit the next button it performs an:

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new VisitorHSAgreement());
```

to the next page, what I want to do is bring them values to display in a label on the next page I have currently tried this but it's coming back null can anybody help me.

```
public string VisitorFirstName { get; set; }
public string VisitorLastName { get; set; }
    var visitorPage = new VisitorPage();

    VisitorFirstName = visitorPage.FindByName<Entry>("FirstNameEntry").Text;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When on `VisitorPage`, there is an instance of the class `VisitorPage`. This instance contains controls, which are instances, too, and might have values set in their properties.

Now you navigating to `VisitorHSAgreement` and try to get a value from the `VisitorPage` by creating a **new** object of this class. Each object of this class comes with its own values and the controls are newly created. Unless you create some static field in `VisitorPage` you will never be able to access the values that are set in the first instance from the new instance. You should *really* read up on basic concepts of OOP, because this is really OOP 101.

I'd suggest to use MVVM along with the Prism library, this will *really* make your Xamarin.Forms life easier. Anyway, if you can't or don't want to at the moment (it's up to you in the end), there is still a solution. Since your properties are public, you can set them *before* navigating to `VisitorHSAgreement`

```
var page = new VisitorHSAgreement()
           {
               VisitorFirstName = FirstNameEntry.Text,
               VisitorLastName = LastNameEntry.Text
           };

await Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn how to work with Object Oriented programming.
As mentioned in the previous answer, you are trying to access empty values from a recently created object (which will obviously empty). While what you need to do is assign the values to the object you want to send, and then send that object (data filled in) to the page you want to use it. 
Then in your page, receive that object sent from the previous page and explore its properties to obtain your values.